# A CRUD api generator for django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am looking to generate Basic CRUD endpoints for models defined in Django 2.0.

For example, if there is a Dog model, with a few fields, I want to generate:

- a GET endpoint to get all dogs
- a GET endpoint to get a dog by ID
- a PUT endpoint to update a dog
- a POST endpoint to create a new dog

I've followed a tutorial on how to create these endpoints, but I would prefer for this to be generated for many models. It seems like redundant work to do this for each model individually rather than have a generator.

I've looked at both *drf-generator* and *django-baker* but they both seem incompatible with django 2.0.

I've used Loopback in the past to do this with Node.js, so I'm looking for something similar for Django.

Is there a fundamental aspect of Django I am missing, or am I simply missing some obvious way to generate these endpoints? Since the admin dashboard already seems to be able to perform these operations, it doesn't seem like such a stretch to expose them externally.

Perhaps I should downgrade to an older version of Django?

Comment: I would suggest you to use DRF(Django Rest Framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) as it is very simple to use.

```
class DogSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = '__all__'

class DogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer = DogSerializer
    model = Dog


from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'dogs', DogViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```